# BadPaddingException: cipher doesn't work when used in two separate methods

Tags: java, encryption

When I encrypt and decrypt in the same method, the cipher works perfectly, however as soon as I send an encrypted message to a server, which sends the same message straight back, the decryption throws a "BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero", any ideas as to why?

Here are my decrpytion and encryption methods, including the method they are called from:

```
    public byte[] getServerResponse(byte[] message) throws IOException
    {
        Log.debug("Getting server response for: " + message.toString());
        byte[] encMsg = encrypt(message);
        out.write(encMsg);
        out.flush();

        in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        byte[] response = new byte[128];
        in.readFully(response);
        byte[] strResponse = decrypt(response);

        Log.debug("Server response: " + response);
        return strResponse;
    }

    private byte[] encrypt(byte[] message) {        
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[128];
        try {                                    
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(message);

        } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }               
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    private byte[] decrypt(byte[] message) {
        byte[] cleartext = new byte[128];
        try {                
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            cleartext = cipher.doFinal(message);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
        return cleartext;
    }
```

The cipher is available to the whole class, and is initialised as follows:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

Do I need to use the IV? If so, how does one do that?

Comment: Are you sure that response is exactly 128 bytes long? Try to use `byte[] response = new byte[ encMsg.length ];` for a start as you say that server just sends the data back. Also try the smoke test of `byte[] response = encMsg;` without sending anything to server at all.

Comment: Test your server sending code. Something tells me that if you stripped out all the encryption and just sent a random byte array, you'd get a different response back.

Comment: @Oleg: I edited the code in my program, as well as above so that the encrypt() method now creates a specifically 128 length byte array, since the key I am using with RSA is 1024 bits long (as according to [link](http://goo.gl/l8o5kQ)), does that not guarantee that the response will be 128 bits? On the server side, I am also specifically creating a byte array of length 128. I'm not familiar with a smoke test, but I'll give that a try, thanks.

Comment: Padding can increase the length of the encrypted data to next multiple of the block size. Initializing the `encryptedBytes` does nothing because it is immediately reassigned to the output of the `cipher.doFinal()`.